# How to retrieve source code of String.GetHashcode() for 64 bits application?

Tags: c#, hashcode

I've made the bad mistake of taking `String.GetHashCode()` for stable so I've build some "unique" 128bits hash by combining 32bits `String.GetHashCode()`. And, indeed in MSDN documentation, I should have not take this method for stable as I did not have the same hash value on a 32bits application.

I can't roll back as all my datas are all written with this mistake.

Don't yell at me on that point.

Right now, I need to recover the actual implementation of GetHashCode() in 64bits plateform in order to stabilize my code.

Is there a place where I can find it ?

This 64bits implementation should return (I use .NET 4.7.0)

```
  "a".GetHashCode() == 372029373; // Should be true
```

Comment: *Hash codes* in `GetHashCode()` are private affairs of the .Net; they can change from version to version, platform to platform etc. Use `Sha128` to create a *stable* hash code.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,0a17bbac4851d0d4,references

Comment: as I said, I can't change the hash system as I need it will cost too much time to update all my datas

Comment: @Rahul : thank you

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - read the question. That ship had already sailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who made the same mistake, I've build this implementation from commentators'documentation. It's the default implementation of the following charachteristics:

- .NET 4 - 4.7.2
- 64 bits
- Release Mode

---

```
public static class StringHashExtensions
{
    public static unsafe int GetHashCode64BitsRelease(this string str)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (char* src = str)
            {
                int hash1 = 5381;
                int hash2 = hash1;

                int c;
                char* s = src;
                while ((c = s[0]) != 0)
                {
                    hash1 = ((hash1 << 5) + hash1) ^ c;
                    c = s[1];
                    if (c == 0)
                        break;
                    hash2 = ((hash2 << 5) + hash2) ^ c;
                    s += 2;
                }

                return hash1 + (hash2 * 1566083941);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```